# Custom HTTP headers are different for tests and httpie

Tags: django, http-headers, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework. In a permissions class I check the value of two custom http headers: `mt_api_token` and `mt_api_key`.

In tests I call the API with my custom headers. `sign_request()` returns `{'mt_api_key': api_client.client_id, 'mt_api_token': token}`.

```
class APIv1SimpleTestCase(APITestCase):
    [...]
    response = self.client.get(url, format='json', **sign_request("", api_client=oauth2_client))
```

This is a legacy system and headers must have underscores instead of dashes.

The permissions class:

```
class AuthPermissions(permissions.BasePermission):
    def is_token_valid(self, request):
        mt_api_token = request.META['mt_api_token']
        [...]
```

Tests pass.
However, if I call the api using httpie:

```
$ http  :8000/api/v1/endpoint1/ mt_api_key:0a9..66 mt_api_token:7b2...8
```

I get keyError exception because `request.META['mt_api_key']` and `request.META['mt_api_token']` don't exist.

I have to use `request.META['HTTP_MT_API_TOKEN']`, which makes sense according to [DRF documentation for `request.META`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META), but I can't find out why tests pass. if I change the implementation to request.META['HTTP_...'] my tests fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working fine in the tests, because the tests are manually setting the `request.META` keys to match what you are passing in, `mt_api_token` and `mt_api_key`. You aren't seeing any errors because this is perfectly valid, but it doesn't match what you are expecting. This is covered very briefly in the [Django advanced testing documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get), but essentially the extra arguments are [directly added](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1aa41dd000e0779c8b1de1f8e7aa4a0f2f752655/django/test/client.py#L370) to the `META` dictionary.

When your request goes through the WSGI handler provided by Django, any HTTP headers are automatically prefixed with `HTTP_` [per the WSGI specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#environ-variables). This applies to most client-provided HTTP headers, including the `Authorization` header which is typically used to authorize users on an API (using Basic authentication, OAuth, etc.), which is put into the `request.META` dictionary as `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION`. Note that the keys are also always uppercase, as HTTP header names are case-insensitive.

You can fix your tests by having your `sign_request` method return the keys as `HTTP_MT_API_TOKEN` and `HTTP_MT_API_KEY`, which are what they would be passed in as when coming through a browser. You will also need to adjust your view code to reference those new keys.

Comment: hi @kevinbrown I didn't want to change the sign_request method without making sure it was sensible. thanks for this fantastic explanation